# Constructor autowiring with a primitive argument

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

Having read about how awesome constructor dependency injection is, I am playing with it right now. Now what confuses me is how can I do constructor autowiring if one of the params are of the primitive type e.g

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Car {

private Category category;
private Fuel fuel;
private String name;

@Autowired
public Car(String name, Category category, Fuel fuel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.fuel = fuel;
    }
```

The constructor is called from the main method:

```
@Component
public final class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ApplicationContext context = AppContext.initAppContext();
        // No xml bean definition as class is a component
        // car name should be initialized to "toyota"
        Car yaris = context.getBean(Car.class);
```

So in the above case I should revert back to field or setter injection?

Comment: You would typically use @Value to annotate the name. What would you like to inject? Where does the name come from?

Comment: update my question to show how the constructor is called

Comment: But which value would you like Spring to pass for the`name` argument?

Comment: any string value e.g "toyota"

Comment: So, you don't care about the value? What's the point of having a string passed as argument if you don't care about the value?